# Correct way to update singletons like factories in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

I have the below controller named MapController
MapController.js

```
var self = this;
self.factory = MapStateFactory;
self.origin = self.factory.originCity;
self.destination = self.factory.destinationCity;

//The wrong way
//Updating self.origin will shadow the value and will no longer point to the factory
self.changeOrigin = function () {
    self.origin = {
        name: 'New Origin'
    };
};

//However, this is still incorrect. 
//It popluates the change in the factory but if I output self.destination on the page, it hasnt updated
self.changeDestination = function () {
    //This also doesn't update both locations if I use
    //MapstateFactory.destinationCity = ''
    self.factory.destination = {
        name: 'New Destination'
    };
};
```

If you just assume that my factory is a standard factory, no funny business, how do I properly update the factory using these functions (which are attached to buttons if make any sense).

This is an issue I am struggline with at the moment. **The only solution I have come across is to do a watch in the value of MapStateFactory.originCity** which seems awfully messy...

I could just do something like

```
self.changeDestination = function () {
   self.destination = {
       name: 'New Destination'
   };
   self.factory.destinationCity = {
       name: 'New Destination'
   };
};
```

But *surely* this is bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

Don't reassign the whole object or you break reference to the original object

Given the following simple example:

```
var a ={name:'foo'}, b=a;
```

You can change the `name` property doing:

```
a.name = 'bar' 
// or
b.name = 'bar'
```

Values of `a.name` and `b.name` will be the same either way.

But if you update `a` by doing :

```
a = {name: 'bar'}
```

you have assigned a completely different object to `a` and broken the reference to the original object. Now `a` and `b` are not referencing the same object so changes made to `a` properties won't affect `b` properties

In your case you would need to change:

```
self.factory.destination = {
    name: 'New Destination'
};
```

To:

```
self.factory.destination.name = 'New Destination' ;
```

Or for bigger changes with multiple properties you can use methods like `angular.extend()`

```
angular.extend(self.factory.destination, {name: 'New Destination', cost:500  });
```

Comment: Cheers for this. It really is one of them things that I needed someone to point out as I had no idea what was going on! Thanks tons!